# How to remove resend confirmation dialog from firefox in magento2

Tags: magento2

When I refresh my magento2 website with ctrl+f5 then firefox popup showing with below message

> "To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier."

This problem are coming when i change store view from frontend and refresh page.
How to disable this firefox pop on magento2 website

[image]